# Pass phpmyadmin database to hostinger

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This isn't a coding question, it's a problem I'm having. The thing is that on phpmyadmin (xampp) I have a user account with password, when I go to hostinger phpmyadmin database I try logging in with that account (typing username and password correctly) and it gives an error: **The MySQL server did not authorize your access**. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP is usually used for local development and hostinger presumably is a hosted account. The two databases have no way of knowing about the other one or synchronizing changes, including any user accounts. Since your XAMPP username and password aren't associated with the hostinger account, you'll need to use the credentials given to you by hostinger for that connection instead.